# Refresh Terminal Window Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, 2d-games

I'm planning on writing a small game in Common Lisp on Mac OSX and I want my character and the enemies to be able to move around on screen. I was hoping to do this by having my program refresh the terminal window at regular intervals. In addition, I'd like the content to refresh in place like emacs and vim do. What's a good way to do this with Common Lisp, with or without a fancy library?

Comment: Please specify your operating system/environment, this could be relevant for the answer.

Comment: Common Lisp doesn't have any standard functions for doing terminal manipulation.

Comment: I would use a fancy library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should take a look here:

https://github.com/lispgames/lispgames.github.io/wiki

it has a section with the resources and fancy libraries here:

https://github.com/lispgames/lispgames.github.io/wiki/Common-Lisp

and finally I recommend this library for 2D graphics it has a great tutorial:

https://github.com/rpav/cl-cairo2/tree/master/tutorial